# Cannot update state with react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

### What I want to do

I want to manage two states with Redux in my React app. The two state is `userName` and `isLogin` which is the boolean value contains whether the user is logging in.

### Codes

I wrote codes with reading some web pages for beginners.

src/components/Login.js

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    };

    this.handleEmail = this.handleEmail.bind(this);
    this.handlePassword = this.handlePassword.bind(this);
    this.handleMainPage = this.handleMainPage.bind(this);
  }

  handleMainPage(){
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state.email);
  }
  handleEmail(event) {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value});
  }
  handlePassword(event) {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Container component="main">
        <CssBaseline />
        <div>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Login
          </Typography>
          <form noValidate>
            <TextField value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmail}/>
            <TextField value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePassword} type="password"/>
            <Button onClick={this.handleMainPage}>
              Sign In
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default Login;
```

src/container/Login.js

```
import Login from '../components/Login';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state, prop) => {
  return {
    userName: state.userName,
    isLogin: state.isLogin,
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onSubmit: (username) => {
      dispatch(login(username))
    }
  }
};

let loginForm = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);

export default loginForm;
```

src/reducers/index.js

```
const defaultState = {
  userName: "",
  isLogin: false,
};

const userStatus = (state=defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      return Object.assign({}, {
        userName: action.userName,
        isLogin: action.isLogin,
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default userStatus;
```

src/actions/index.js

```
export const login = (username) => {
  return {
    type: 'LOGIN',
    userName: username,
    isLogin: true,
  };
}
```

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import MainWindow from './Main';
import userStatus from './reducers';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

var Routes = (
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
    <Route path='/login' component={App} />
    <Route path='/signup' component={App} />
    <Route path='/main' component={MainWindow} />
  </Route>
);

let store = createStore(userStatus);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <Router>{Routes}</Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I checked `action.userName` and `action.isLogin` in src/reducers/index.js have values that I entered in the login form, but in the src/components/Login.js these values are empty and false (initial state).

How to update these state correctly?

Comment: Is your `LOGIN` action dispatched?

Comment: I think I do in `mapDispatchToProps` function in src/container/Login.js. Is it wrong?

Comment: Nope it seems fine but, have you checked in the Redux Devtool that your action is actually dispatched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not submitting your form. you need a function (usually a handleSubmit) to submit the form. So something like this:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
// ...
  <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" type="submit">
     Add note
  </Button>
</form>
```

and your handleSubmit function looks something like -->

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
// if your input value is truthy, then add input to state
    if (noteText) {
      dispatch({
        type: "ADD_NOTE",
        noteText,
        id: uuid(),
        dateCreated: Date()
      });
    }
    // set input value back to empty string
    setNoteText("");
    // don't let page refresh so your state is saved
    e.preventDefault();
  };
```

Comment: I'd like to clarify I am not using redux but rather mimicking redux with useContext, useReducer, and useState

Comment: Also looking at this more it may be an issue with what you named your objects as there are some discrepancies in the dispatch

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I set `type="submit"` on button and wrote `handleSubmit` function for form. Then, moving the `this.props.onSubmit` function into the `handleSubmit`, it worked!